# Compiling 3rd party framework with Qt 5.1.1

Tags: macos, qt, linker, clang, qt5

I've been happily compiling projects with 3rd party frameworks in Qt 5.0. After upgrading to Qt 5.1, the 3rd party frameworks can no longer be found by the linker.

There's a Qt bug report [here](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-31552?focusedCommentId=205820&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-205820), but I see that the item has been closed. At the bottom of the report a comment states: -

> To build and link against a framework in /Library/Frameworks (the following should be added to the .pro file):

```
QMAKE_OBJECTIVE_CFLAGS += -F/Library/Frameworks
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -F/Library/Frameworks
QMAKE_LINK += -framework Foo
```

When I do this, it has no effect. Also, the 3rd party framework is a C++ library, so using QMAKE_OBJECTIVE_CFLAGS will not help. I tried substituting this for QMAKE_CXXFLAGS, but it still fails.

In addition, when adding QMAKE_OBJECTIVE_CFLAGS and QMAKE_LINK to the .pro file, Qt Creator doesn't highlight them as known compiler flags.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem, without reverting back to Qt 5.0?

Comment: To whomever downvoted, please explain why; doing so without an explanation is not constructive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was due to the fact that the .pro file already referenced the 3rd party library, when using Qt 5.0, like this: -

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -F /Library/Frameworks/otherlibrary.framework/
LIBS += -framework otherlibrary
```

I did not realise that although the QMAKE_LFLAGS included the path to the specific framework, it also needs the path to the root of the frameworks: -

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -F/Library/Frameworks
```

Adding that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You're a bit unclear on what exactly you're doing, and how it fails.

If you're trying to use the framework from a .cpp file, you need indeed to also set `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -F/Library/Frameworks`, and possibly also `QMAKE_CFLAGS` (the example in the bug report assumes the framework exposes Objective-C bindings. I will correct that)

Try this, and re-open the bug report with logs and ways to reproduce if it still fails.

*(The missing highlight of Qt Creator is not relevant, they are both still qmake variables.)*

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes, I may be a bit unclear on what's going on, especially as it doesn't work for me! I know the objective-c flag is irrelevant, though I posted it as it was a quote from the example. I tried substituting it for the QMAKE_CXXFLAGS and QMAKE_CFLAGS, but that didn't work either. As for QtCreator, it was just a suggestion that perhaps it should be picking it up, but I'm not relying on that. I'll clean the project, try again and let you know how it goes. Thanks.